# Unity3d object still moveable on pause

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a simple pong game and when I pause the game by hitting the escape key, the user can still move the paddle left and right. The game is a mobile game that involves touch. How would I go about ensuring the paddle is not moveable when the game is paused as well?

Here is the code for my paddle if this helps:

```
private var ray : Ray;
private var hit : RaycastHit;

function Start () {

}

function Update () {
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, hit)){
            transform.position.x = hit.point.x;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my pause script:

```
var gamePaused : boolean = false;
var back : Texture2D;
var GUIskin:GUISkin;
var ClickSound:AudioClip;

function Start(){
    Time.timeScale=1;
    gamePaused = false;
    gameObject.GetComponent(PauseMenu).enabled = false;
}

function OnGUI(){
    GUI.skin = GUIskin;

    GUI.Box (Rect (Screen.width - 550,Screen.height - 700,400,200), back);
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width - 510,Screen.height - 615,120,80), "Main                      Menu")) {
        Application.LoadLevel("Menu");
        audio.PlayOneShot(ClickSound);
    }
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width - 310,Screen.height - 615,120,80), "Quit")) {
        audio.PlayOneShot(ClickSound);
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Also here's my pause controller:

```
private var gamePaused : boolean = false;

function Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)){
        if(gamePaused){
            Time.timeScale=1;
            gamePaused = false;
            gameObject.GetComponent(PauseMenu).enabled = false;
        }
        else{
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            gamePaused = true;
            gameObject.GetComponent(PauseMenu).enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you implement pausing?

Comment: Yes, umm, where is your pausing code?

Answer (score 3):

Your paddle script is never told to check for your pause state.

In your update code you need to add a check here for some pause state:

```
function Update () {
    if(!gamePaused){
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if(Physics.Raycast(ray, hit)){
                transform.position.x = hit.point.x;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct. Setting `Timescale` to 0 only works for movement combined with deltaTime afaik. When timeScale is set to zero the game is basically paused if all your functions are frame rate independent.

Comment: @Joetjah - right. if you want to do a "slow motion" effect then you'd use that to affect all scripts that are using Time.deltaTime.

Answer (score 0):

Just check to see whether the game is paused in your paddle's Update function, and if so, exit the function without moving the paddle. For example:

```
if(Time.timeScale == 0) return;
```

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. You can still move the paddle back and forth. I don't want users to be able to constantly pause the game to reposition the paddle where they want. Takes away the challenge. :D